# looping through an array and for each item capturing string before '-' and re constructing a new array

Tags: javascript

This might be very simple and I am missing something obvious

I am only concerned with what ever I have before the '_' in the array items and create a new array out of that. Here is how I am trying to do this

```
var x = ['P0000004_604990244255', 'P11100012_604990244823', 'P0002346722_604990112823'];

//x_trim = ['P0000004', 'P11100012', 'P0002346722']; this is how the new array should look like


var x_trim = '[';

for(var i = 0; i<= x.length; x++){
    x_trim += '"' + x[i].split('_')[0] + '",';
}
x_trim += ']';
x_trim = x_trim.substring(0, x_trim.length - 2)+ ']';

x_trim = eval(x_trim);
console.log(x_trim)
```

It is only returning the first item of the array in the correct format. I am not able to iterate through the array. Or is there a better way of doing this? It has to pure javascript..no jQuery

Comment: Check your `for` loop. Should you be incrementing `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var x = ['P0000004_604990244255', 'P11100012_604990244823', 'P0002346722_604990112823'];
var arr = [];
for(var i=0;i<x.length; i++)arr[i] = x[i].split("_")[0];
```

Comment: I like the idea of getting the array through new Array than concatenating it like a string and then running an eval(). This makes sense..I mean after @hugomg pointed my mistake it works fine. But I will go this route

Comment: @soum Using `eval` typically does *not* make sense.

Comment: Don't use `new Array()`. Just do `[]` instead. Also, you are noit declaring `arrTemp` so its currently a global by default!

Comment: NOM3 edited his answer just now to fix it. For the array, you are supposed to use `[]` where you would have used `new Array()` and for variables, all of them should be declared with `var` at some point (like we did with `x` and `arr`) or they will be treated as global variables by default.

Comment: @hugomg i just removed the temp array all together, it wasnt broken, so there wasnt anything to fix

Comment: @soum i have edited the answer it is now refined, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop is wrong,. It should look like

```
for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
```

You should do `i++` instead of `x++` and `i` should stop just before `x.length` instead of at `<=` (due to 0-based indexing)

Comment: That one was obvious..well embarrassing actually :-)..thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `substring()` and `indexOf()`, no need to `split()` anything. It comes out with much simpler and cleaner looking code:

```
var x = [  'P0000004_604990244255', 
           'P11100012_604990244823', 
           'P0002346722_604990112823'  ];
var y = [];

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   var s = x[i];
   y.push(s.substring(0, s.indexOf('_')));
}

console.log(y);
// logs
// ["P0000004", "P11100012", "P0002346722"]
```

Comment: for-in loops aren't guaranteed to loop the array in order and they can also pick up stuff from Array.prototype depending on what browesr you use. I usually think its better to stick with regular for loops for array iteration.